# Google maps in firefox6 zooms znd scrolls page

Tags: firefox, google-maps

I have problem with Firefox6 (don't know if it also concerns earlier versions).

I want to embed Google Map on page, and when page has scrollbars (is longer than viewport) mouse wheel not only zooms map but also scrolls page. I tried to catch mousewheel event and stop propagation but this event isn catchable when cursor os over map. When cursor is over map controls (zoom control, google logo, etc) i can catch event and stop propagation.

What is more strange it not happens always. Sometimes page srolls and after few scrolls it stops and mousewheel only zooms map (as expected). Sometimes page doesn't scroll and sometimes it scrolls with zoom all the time. Can't find pattern.

Source code is simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function(){
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.25, 21.01);
            mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            streetViewControl: false,
            zoomControl:true,
            mapTypeControl:false
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <p style="height:500px;">-lot of text-</p>
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px; height:500px;"></div>
        <p style="height:500px;">-lot of text-</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is also described on code.google.com, this problem is only in Firefox, but it isn't a Firefox bug:

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3652
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1605

Have also found out a workaround, that is not re-scrolling or re-zooming and works fine:

A new ScrollInterceptOverlay derived from google.maps.OverlayView, prepending a div on MapPanes.overlayMouseTarget:

### Version with jQuery

```
// Ensure to have google.maps loaded:
// var gmap = new google.maps.Map($googlemap[0], mapOptions);

// Define a ScrollInterceptOverlay function
var ScrollInterceptOverlay = function (gmap) {
  if (!(this instanceof ScrollInterceptOverlay)) return;

  var $div;
  var $mapDiv;

  var initialize = function () {
    $div = $('<div />').css({
      position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0,
      display: 'inline-block'
    });

    var div = $div[0];
    if (div && div.addEventListener) {
      // Internet Explorer, Opera, Google Chrome and Safari
      div.addEventListener("mousewheel", mouseScrollStop);
      // Firefox
      div.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", mouseScrollStop);
      div.addEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll", mouseScrollStop);
    }
    else if (div && div.attachEvent) { // IE before version 9
      div.attachEvent("onmousewheel", mouseScrollStop);
    }

    this.setMap(gmap);
  };

  var mouseScrollStop = function (e) {
    if (e && e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
  };

  this.onAdd = function () {
    $div.prependTo(this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget);
  };

  this.onRemove = function () {

    var div = $div[0];
    if (div && div.addEventListener) {
      // Internet Explorer, Opera, Google Chrome and Safari
      div.addEventListener("mousewheel", mouseScrollStop);
      // Firefox
      div.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", mouseScrollStop);
      div.addEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll", mouseScrollStop);
    }
    else if (div && div.attachEvent) { // IE before version 9
      div.attachEvent("onmousewheel", mouseScrollStop);
    }

    $div.detach();
  };

  this.draw = function () {
    if ($mapDiv && $mapDiv.length === 1) {
      $div.css({
        width: $mapDiv.outerWidth(),
        height: $mapDiv.outerHeight()
      });
    }
  };

  var base_setMap = this.setMap;
  this.setMap = function (map) {
    $mapDiv = $(map.getDiv());
    base_setMap.call(this, map);
  };

  initialize.call(this);
};
// Setup prototype as OverlayView object
ScrollInterceptOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

// Now create a new ScrollInterceptOverlay OverlayView object:
var mapScrollInterceptor = new ScrollInterceptOverlay(gmap);
```

This workaround is using jQuery, required for calculating outerWidth and outerHeight, but also for better reading.

### Version with pure javaScript

Tested live: http://fiddle.jshell.net/fhSMM/7/

```
// Ensure to have google.maps loaded:
// var gmap = new google.maps.Map(googlemap, mapOptions);

// Define a ScrollInterceptOverlay class function
var ScrollInterceptOverlay = function () {
  if (!(this instanceof ScrollInterceptOverlay)) return;

  var div;

  // private instance function
  var mouseScrollStop = function (e) {
    if (e && e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
  };

  // public instance function
  this.onAdd = function () {
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.display = 'inline-block';
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.style.top = div.style.left = 0;

    if (div.addEventListener) {
      // Internet Explorer, Opera, Google Chrome and Safari
      div.addEventListener("mousewheel", mouseScrollStop);
      // Firefox
      div.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", mouseScrollStop);
      div.addEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll", mouseScrollStop);
    }
    else if (div.attachEvent) { // IE before version 9
      div.attachEvent("onmousewheel", mouseScrollStop);
    }

    var pane = this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget;
    var firstChild = pane.firstChild;
    if (!firstChild) {
      pane.appendChild(div);
    }
    else {
      pane.insertBefore(div, firstChild);
    }
  };

  // public instance function
  this.onRemove = function () {
    if (div) {
      if (div.removeEventListener) {
        // Internet Explorer, Opera, Google Chrome and Safari
        div.removeEventListener("mousewheel", mouseScrollStop);
        // Firefox
        div.removeEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", mouseScrollStop);
        div.removeEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll", mouseScrollStop);
      }
      else if (div.detachEvent) { // IE before version 9
        div.detachEvent("onmousewheel", mouseScrollStop);
      }

      var parent = div.parentNode;
      parent.removeChild(div);
    }

    // do not delete div var'iable
    div = undefined;
  };

  // public instance function
  this.draw = function () {
    var map = this.getMap();
    if (map) {
      var mapDiv = map.getDiv();
      if (mapDiv) {
        var rect = mapDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
        div.style.width = rect.width + 'px';
        div.style.height = rect.height + 'px';
      }
    }
  };

};
// Setup prototype as OverlayView object
ScrollInterceptOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

// Now create a new ScrollInterceptOverlay OverlayView object:
var mapScrollInterceptor = new ScrollInterceptOverlay();
mapScrollInterceptor.setMap(gmap);
```

Please visit also http://metadea.de/V/ about what (real) javaScript class functions are, and why I like jQuery :)

Works now for me.
Also in Firefox, the map is zooming on mousescroll, but no more scrolling the document.

Edit: Updated support for MozMousePixelScroll, refined jS

Answer (score 4):

For now it looks like [firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=681200). Will close question when bug will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

You could try to start Firefox with a brand new profile (e.g. by starting the Profile Manager - executing 'firefox -P' on windows systems - and choosing 'Create...') and see if the problem persists.

I had several old but seemingly empty user profiles lying around in the VMs I used to verify if this was a bug in FF 6 and obviously installing only the new binaries didn't help. **On the other hand, creating a blank profile did**, so I can only think of this being a migration glitch. If major versions of FF are going to be released on a bi-monthly basis, though, a lot of people are going to suffer from similar issues.

Comment: I have tried this but problem still exists. I also noticed that when i zoom slowly (eg. one step per second) there is no way to stop scrolling page, but when i zoom really fast page doesn't scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Why not take UI control of zooming? This works well for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="canvas" style="width:600px;height:400px;"></div>
    <script>
        // Load event
        $(function() {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map($('.canvas')[0], myOptions);
            var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
            overlay.draw = function() {};
            overlay.setMap(map);

            // Only a Mozilla bug
            if($.browser.mozilla) {
                // Wait for the map DOM to be ready
                google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
                    $('.canvas > div > div:first-child > div').bind('DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
                        // setTimeout needed otherwise the return false has no effect
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            // Calculate new center
                            var offset = $('.canvas').offset();
                            var pos = overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(e.pageX-offset.left, e.pageY-offset.top));

                            // Calculate new zoom level
                            var zoom = map.getZoom();
                            if(e.detail < 0) zoom++;
                            else if(e.detail > 0) zoom--;

                            map.setCenter(pos);
                            map.setZoom(zoom);
                        }, 1);

                    // Stop propagation (prevent default)
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way, scrolling over the map-controls first (like the zoom bar), and than over the map resolves the bug temporarily (until you scroll again outsite the map). Maybe someone could come up with a solution to mimic that user action on mouseenter?